# A periodic message

Tags: cipher

I was wandering around Washington, D.C., recently, not paying attention to where I was, thinking about codes and ciphers, when suddenly it hit me. No, really: a blast of wind blew a paper right into my face. I looked at it and saw the following:

> 0589-9443-2472-6354-0391-2302-2375-7868-2378-8968-0733-5229-2314-7539

I looked up and determined that I was on Independence Avenue between First and Second Streets, SE. Then I looked down at the paper again and realized it was telling me to go somewhere and use a certain door. Where and what door?

Comment: Now if I only had a table to decode this, `B Ac PuTc CrHf` no that doesn't work

Comment: I have a different theory about "periodic" but haven't been able to make it work so far.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan just FYI I've just edited the question

Comment: The edit you mention is entirely consistent with my theory about what "periodic" is referring to, but I'm still a few insights short of actually being able to do anything with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am wandering around Washington, D.C, paying closely attention to where I am, thinking about this riddle I am trying to solve. But nothing is gonna hit me.

I have a paper in my hands on which I wrote the following

> LA Building, Hermes
>  LAC Bldg A, Hermegs

Can anyone help me to identify this building? I must find and use his door!

**Edit:**

Suddenly my phone rings. Its M Oehm. He tells me to go back to the Library. He sounds very excited.

> M Oehm: "Perhaps [here](https://www.loc.gov/item/thc1995011690/PP/?loclr=blogadm)? The rooms of the [building in question](https://www.loc.gov/visit/maps-and-floor-plans/john-adams-building/fifth-floor/) have the right letter code."
>
>  He found out, that **John Adams Building**, the name of the LoC building, is abbreviated with **LA**, maybe LA5 points us to the fifth floor of the library. And even better, Hermes is there.

I hung up and started running back to the library.

> At the [west entrance](https://www.loc.gov/loc/walls/adams.html#wedoors) from 2nd Street I finally found it. The [Hermes-Door](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Adams_Building#Bronze_entrance_doors_by_Lee_Lawrie).
>  The first line on my paper was correct: LA Building, Hermes.

For those interested what I wrote on my paper:

> Washington, D.C, at Independence Avenue between First and Second Streets, SE is the **Library of Congress**
>  The numbers given are valid ISSN Numbers, searchable at the [LoC Website](https://catalog.loc.gov/index.html).
>  The found records have a blast of informations, I chose the Library of Congress **Call Number**
>
>  ISSN Number  **Call Number**
>  0589-9443   **LA5.C64**
>  2472-6354   **BL1**
>  0391-2302   **DG11.A57**
>  2375-7868   **HE1**
>  2378-8968   **RM1**
>  0733-5229   **E839.G37**
>  2314-7539   **S1**
>
>  Now, only taking letters into account that gives
>  LA5BL1DG11HE1RM1E839S1 -> LABLDGHERMES  -> LA Building, Hermes
>  or with Sub-Item-Number
>  LAC5C64Bl1DG11A57HE1RM1E839G37S1 -> LACBLDGAHERMEGS -> LAC Bldg A, Hermegs
>
>  Note: All entries are classified as **periodic** or newspaper ("*a periodic message*")

Maybe this leads to an answer? Maybe I'm stuck wandering around in Washington, D.C.

Finally, there is a happy end.
Thanks to **M Oehm** for "calling" me, I would never have looked there.

Comment: You're correct! Now you just need to find the building and the door. +1.

Comment: Perhaps [here](https://www.loc.gov/item/thc1995011690/PP/?loclr=blogadm)? The rooms of the [building in question](https://www.loc.gov/visit/maps-and-floor-plans/john-adams-building/fifth-floor/) have the right letter code.